# Why does my bash code change when I write it to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I have been trying to write this for loop to a file:

```
echo "for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo $i; done" >> test.sh
```

It should make a file that will print the numbers 1 to 4. But whenever I run this the output is `4 4 4 4` each appearing on a new line.

When I look at the sh file the `do echo $i` I entered has changed to `do echo 4`. The rest of the code is the same.

Is there some syntax that I'm missing?

Comment: Between double quotes, `$i` expands before `echo` is run. You need to use single quotes to prevent that.

Comment: @oguzismail Both this solution and John's work. Is there one that I should use over the other in the future?

Comment: Depends. Like, if you have too many variable references in the string, wrapping it in single quotes is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$i` is being evaluated by the outer shell. Escape the dollar sign to ensure a literal dollar sign is echoed.

```
echo "for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo \$i; done" >> test.sh
```

Or use single quotes to prevent any expansion within the string.

```
echo 'for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo $i; done' >> test.sh
```